# MySQL: Change Collation from utf8_bin to utf8_unicode_ce

Tags: mysql, collation

Given a full table, how do I change the collation from utf8_bin to utf8_unicode_ce? The normal "alter" query does not work, because of "duplicate entry errors". For example there are two entries

```
David Hussa
```

and

```
David Hußa
```

I know they are the same. Is there an elegant way to tell MySQL to "merge" the entrys? I should mention, that the id of the entries are used in other tables as reference so this has to be respected too by MySQL. Or do I have to do this the long and annoying way: Means merging every duplicate manually and then change the collation?

The table looks like this:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_FULLTEXT` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=930710 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Stores all authors from dblp.xml.'$$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete the duplicate entries:

```
DELETE  a2
FROM    authors a1
JOIN    authors a2
ON      a2.name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI = a1.name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI
        AND a2.id < a1.id
```

Note that this may take long time if your table is large.

It would be better to do this:

- Drop the `UNIQUE` constraint
- Change the collation
- Create a plain, non-unique index on `name`
- Run the query (without `COLLATE` clause):

  ```
  DELETE  a2
  FROM    authors a1
  JOIN    authors a2
  ON      a2.name = a1.name
          AND a2.id < a1.id
  ```
- Drop the index
- Recreate the `UNIQUE` constraint.

To update the referencing tables, run this queries before deleting the entries:

```
UPDATE  child c
JOIN    (
        (
        SELECT  name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS name_ci, MAX(id) AS mid
        FROM    authors
        GROUP BY
                name_ci
        ) pa
        JOIN    authors a
        ON      a.name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = name_ci
        )
ON      c.author = a.id
SET     author = mid;
```

on all referencing tables.

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing. But a question remains: If the id of a name is used in another table, and the name was a duplicate. Is this automatically updated by the "other" id? I mean if "John Doe" has id=1 and "John Doé" has id=2, the second id is lost, right?

Comment: @Aufwind: sorry, didn't understand what you mean at first. No, it won't update the names automatically. You will have to run the queries which I'll write now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It worked smoothless. For other noobies like me I want to add these comments: child is the name of a referencing table and c is its abbreviation, that is used in e.g. c.author in the second last line. Took me some time to figure that out for myself. ^^